Type agnostic wrapper class for deprecating context variables in Flask/Jinja (Python)
Summary
Looking for a way to deprecate variables in Jinja templates without breaking backwards compatibility. PoC'ed a wrapper class. Concept works, but many code smells.
Background
I am working on a large system written in Python, using Flask and Jinja templates. There are hundreds of views, exposing thousands of context variables rendered in Jinja templates. There are also thousands of templates, scattered across many implementations of our system. Of course there is structure there, but there is no clear way of knowing which implementation or which templates uses which context variable.
In the course of time, we have marked many variables as deprecated. To not break backwards compatibility, this is done by either hardcoding a variable to None or an empty string. If we would actually remove the variable, rendering the templates would break. Grepping through all templates, changing them and deploying them is way to cumbersome and error prone.
Proof of concept
I am not interested in when the deprecated variables are instantiated (which happens in the views), but I want to know when they are actually used in a template. 'Used' can mean many things in this context, since context variables can be pretty much any 'simple' Python object, like str, int, float, Decimal, list, dict, etc. So 'being used' could mean:

Performed calculations on (templates doing business logic on integers, decimals, floats)
Being checked for existence or truthiness
Being interpolated in a template (simple string operation)
Elements in variable being accessed
etc.

My proof of concept consists of a small class, that acts as a wrapper around a context variable. It implements all basic Python object methods and calls a log() in each of those.
class DeprecatedContextVariable:
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

    def log(self):
        logger.warning(f'Deprecated context variable used: {self.name}')

    def __str__(self):
        self.log()
        return f'{self.value}'

    def __bool__(self):
        self.log()
        return bool(self.value)

    def __iter__(self):
        self.log()
        return iter(self.value)

    def __add__(self, other):
        self.log()
        return self.value + other

    def __sub__(self, other):
        self.log()
        return self.value - other

    def __radd__(self, other):
        self.log()
        return self.value + other

    def __rsub__(self, other):
        self.log()
        return other - self.value


# Old usage
from flask import render_template

context = {
    'name': 'foo',
    'age': 32
    'preferences': {
        'darkmode': True
    }
}
render_template('my-template.html', **context)

# New usage
context = {
    'name': 'foo',
    'age': DeprecatedContextVariable('age', 32)
    'preferences': DeprecatedContextVariable('preferences', {
        'darkmode': True
    })
}
render_template('my-template.html', **context)

This does work. It also has many code smells that makes me wonder if there is a better way. For instance: each and every core method of all types that might get wrapped has to be implemented. If one is forgotten, rendering the template will crash. Also, this might add functionality to certain types, that they normally don't have. E.g. if one of the templates does a ceil() on an int value, the wrapper would have to implent __ceil__, but that doesn't make sense for other types. It also might not hurt, but it is a code smell.
What are my options? Is there a Flask or Jinja feature or a Python internal that I could leverage, or a 3rd party library? Would it make sense to use a base class for known and most used types (str, int, list, dict, bool), that makes sure that all operations are accounted for? That might lead to operations not getting logged if the corresponding dunder methods isn't custom implemented.

You could write your DeprecatedContextVariable using the __getattr__ functiontion, which makes it more flexible:
class DeprecatedContextVariable:
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self._name = name
        self._value = value

    def _log(self):
        logger.warning(f'Deprecated context variable used: {self._name}')

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        self._log()
        return getattr(self._value, name)


It's a bit different in that the log() method is not called when invoking the wrapped function but when retrieving it, but I guess that it would be fine in your case.
